# Getting error while solving question on HackerRank, and server is MySql

Tags: mysql, syntax-error

I am solving question on Hackerrank and RDBMS is mysql
This is code

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT salary, months * salary AS totals
    FROM employee
)
SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY totals) AS rk
FROM cte;
```

the code is correct, still getting error

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'cte AS (
> SELECT salary, months * salary AS totals
> FROM employee
> )
> SELECT' at line 1

GETING error whenever i try to print cte table

Comment: Which version of MySQL is used at HackerRank? CTE are only supported in version 8 or higher ...

Comment: You can `SELECT FROM (SELECT ....)` if you need older style notation.